# Add new resource in restfull with Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a `messages` resource:

```
@Path("/messages")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public class MessageResource {

...

@Path("/{msgId}/comments")
public CommentsResource getCommentsResource() {
    return new CommentsResource();
}
```

Now i want to add a new comment for a particular `messageId`,

So here is the `comments` resource:

```
@Path("/")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public class CommentsResource {

@POST
public Comment addNewComment(Comment newComment, @PathParam("msgId") long messageId) {
    commentService.addComment(messageId, newComment);
    return newComment;
}
```

and here is `commentService.addComment`:

```
public Comment addComment(long msgId, Comment newComment) {
    Map<Long, Comment> allCommentsOfAMessage = messages.get(msgId).getComments();

    newComment.setId(allCommentsOfAMessage.size() + 1);
    allCommentsOfAMessage.put(newComment.getId(), newComment);
    return newComment;
}
```

But problem is that the `addNewComment()` method of the `CommentsResource` class never been called with some URL like: `http://localhost:8080/messages/2/comments`

Including a new comment in Json format by `POST` method.

(This URL should add a new comment to message with Id=2)

Comment: So what's happening, are you getting a 404? I've tested with what you have provided and it works just fine. There are threee other options, but it shouldn't matter because the above already works, but I'll still mention them. 1) You can return the `CommentResource.class`, just have the method return type `Class`. 2) You could inject `@Context ResourceContext resourceContext;` and in the method return `resourceContext.getResource(CommentResource.class)`. 3) You can change the return type to `Resource` and return `Resource.from(CommentResource.class);`. Also remove `@Path("/")` unless it...

Comment: ... should be accessible from that path, which I don't think you want. Sub resource classes don't need the annotation

Comment: If it still doesn't work, please try and put everything into a single `JerseyTest` class, as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160440/jersey-client-api-vs-jersey-test-framework/27162589#27162589), then post it. It will be easier for us to test and debug if we have a running example that reproduces the problem. See more information about [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for help, it works, i think i was just an IDE problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jersey documentation says that you can do this in a way such as the root resource is /messages/comments/{msgId}. It probably cannot propagate the pathparam if you catch it in the root resource and not in the sub-resource.

Maybe you should just have them in the same class or have comments as a root resource like POST /comments/{msgId}.